# Margin on a button within a div: does anyone know why there's a little white margin on top and on the right of the button?

Tags: html, css

Does anyone know why there's a little white margin on top and on the right of the button?

```css
.form {
    border: 1px solid hsl(0, 36%, 70%);
    border-radius: 4rem;
    overflow: hidden;}

.email-box {
    padding: 1.6rem 2.8rem;
    flex: 1;width: 100%;
    border: 0;}

.arrow-button {
    cursor: pointer;
    float: right;
    border: none;
    background-color: hsl(0, 80%, 86%);
    padding: 0 2rem;}
```

```html
<form class="flex form" action="">  
  <input class="email-box" type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email Address">  
  <button class="arrow-button" type="submit"><img src="images/icon-arrow.svg" alt="arrow"></button>  
</form>
```

[image: picture of the button]

The button shouldn't have the white margin on the top and on the right.

Answer (score 0):

Try this CSS

```
.form {
    border: 1px solid hsl(0, 36%, 70%);
    border-radius: 4rem;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: flex; /*makes the children stretch over the whole parent height, which leads to removing the margin that you have*/
    flex-direction:row; /*optional*/ }

.email-box {
    padding: 1.6rem 2.8rem;
    flex: 1;width: 100%;
    border: 0; }

.arrow-button {
    cursor: pointer;
    float: right;
    border: none;
    background-color: hsl(0, 80%, 86%);
    padding: 0 2rem; }
```

Comment: .form is already flex. I use another class only for flex which is on the html. Unfortunately the margin remains.

Comment: Can you provide the flex class as well?

Comment: The problem must be with the picture, since I dont have the picture, i replace the arrow picture with " > " and it just works fine

Comment: It's just: 
.flex {
    display: flex;
}

I tried changing the picture or putting no picture but for some reason the margin remains. I just solved it by using box-shadow instead of border:
.form {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px hsl(0, 36%, 70%);
    border-radius: 4rem;
    overflow: hidden;
}